# MessageRequest().Builder() unresolvable using IBM Cloud Conversation Service in Java

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

I am writing a piece of software in Java which implements the IBM Watson Java API, specifically the conversation section. What is confusing me is the below line being incorrect:

```
    String userInput = input;

    MessageRequest newMessage = new MessageRequest.Builder().inputText(input).context(context).build();
```

I have used IBMs Watson API for Android and every piece of research I have done have specified the use of a MessageRequest().Builder() yet when  I try and implement that piece of code I get the following error:

```
"Cannot Resolve Symbol 'Builder'
```

Any ideas as to why would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Try it..

```
MessageOptions newMessage = new MessageOptions.Builder().workspaceId("")
                .input(new InputData.Builder(input).build()).context(context).build();
        MessageResponse response = service.message(newMessage).execute();
```

I think you are using older version of sdk.
Update it https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/releases
 Message request is no longer available. Use MessageOptions.